# Difference between Frame and Canvas tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

What is the difference between a Frame and Canvas in tkinter? I'm a beginner in tkinter, and I don't really see any difference between the two... I've been using them interchangeably. Are they the same or is there some sort of internal or external difference?

Comment: A `Frame` is designed to be a parent container of other widgets. A `Canvas` is like a canvas that you can draw somethings on it like lines, circles, text, etc.  A `Canvas` can be used as a parent container as well but it is not designed for that at the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Frame` is designed to be a container for other widgets. It really doesn't do anything but provide a border and color, and to collect a set of widgets into a logical group.

A `Canvas` is something that can act as a container for other widgets (as can just about any widget), but it also has features that let you draw circles, lines, rectangles, and other objects on it.

A Canvas can also be scrolled, whereas a frame cannot.